# How to use two conditions in conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to use both "text contains" and "text exactly is" at the same time with a logical "OR" in between.

How can I do this with custom formula?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting uses custom formula.

For column A:A the formula may be:

`=or($A1 = "text1", regexmatch($A1, "text2") )`

`regexmatch` is a simple and powerful way to check text contains.

Comment: Yeah since you set it up once and you can add several conditions at once (instead of setting up multiple conditions separately).